# Python Jupyter Notebook: Specify cell execution order

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have a Jupyter notebook.
In the cell 1, I defined a lot of functions, which need to run before other things. Then in the following cells, I start to present result.
However, when I convert to HTML, this layout is ugly. Readers have to scroll a long time to see the result and they may not care about the functions at all.
But I have to put the code in that order because I need those functions.

So my question is, is there a way I could control the run order of cells after I click run all? or is there a way I could do something like the following.
I put all my function definitions in cell 20, then in cell 1, I could say tell Jupyter something like "run cell 20".

Just curious if this is doable.
Thanks.

Comment: There is an extension called [`init_cell`](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/init_cell) that adds a button to the toolbar and "initializes" or runs specific cells whenever the notebook is restarted.  This requires installing nbextensions if not already installed and indicating specific cells via View > Cell Toolbar > Initialisation Cell menu.

Comment: I'm personally running the notebooks twice to solve the problem you have (using `if` to only run the first cells at the 2nd iteration).

Comment: @pistache actually I will run the notebook on a daily basis. So I would like to automate it using nbconvert.

Comment: We're [working on](https://github.com/michaelpacer/hiding_tags_nbconvert) mechanisms to hide code cells from nbconvert output.

Comment: FYI what you're asking is literate programming in Jupyter. It's what I wanted too…

Answer (score 4):

I would save the functions as a separate module, then import this module at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Such a functionality, (to my knowledge) is not available in Jupyter as of yet. However, if you are really worried about having a lot of function definitions at the beginning and want to hide them, you can do the following alternative:

1. Define the functions in a Python script.
2. Add the script execution to the first coding cell of your notebook
3. Add the remaining of the code to the consecutive cells of the notebook
4. Optionally, show its contents at the end of the notebook for viewers' convenience.

Comment: When you say "yet", do you mean they will include in future release? Or in "jupyterlab"? Yeah, import as a module sounds like the best thing I could do now.

Comment: I came here looking for a way to make preamble be placed at the end, because of [this thoughtful article on literate programming and code presentation order](https://getpocket.com/a/read/730903290).  I like this answer because it _mostly_ moves the details asside, but then consideres displaying them after.  Very good work-around!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [execution_dependencies](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/execution_dependencies) nbextension. With that, you can define dependencies on the order of the execution of your cells.

To use tags on your cells:
View - Cell Toolbar - Tags

E.g.:

Add tags to your cells

Cell 1 - #HTML, =>functions

```
print(txt)
```

...

Cell 20 - #functions

```
txt = 'functions'
```

When you run Cell 1 it will output 'functions' because it will run cell 20 first.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Runtools](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/wiki/Runtools) nbextension, which allows you to run selected cells.